# Regex to replace sql table's individual dashes with =

Tags: python, regex

I have a text content, which contains sql statement's output in the form of a table.

I want to replace the dashes of this table with any other character like "=".

Below is the content.

```
some text
SomeTxt: dummy text is here
Below points are good:
-Kotlin
-Angular 6
Kotlin is programing language -_- Angular is also one, just testing text with -



   id          employee
-------------  ------------------------------
   2           Tom
   4           Alice
   7           Alice-tim
   8           Alice -tome
   9           Aloce - Alice    

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I do not want this last line to be converted.

The regex I have tried is `(?<!\w)-\s{2}(?!\w)`.

It matches the last - in this string also

```
Kotlin is programing language -_- Angular is also one, just testing text with -
```

Also, it does not match all the individual regex.

I want the output to be like below.

```
some text
SomeTxt: dummy text is here
Below points are good:
-Kotlin
-Angular 6
Kotlin is programing language -_- Angular is also one, just testing text with -



   id          employee
=============  ==============================
   2           Tom
   4           Alice
   7           Alice-tim
   8           Alice -tome
   9           Aloce - Alice
```

Comment: What is the exact requirement? `r'\B-{2,}\B'` will work with this example, but you probably want to match the whole line with `-`s, like `re.sub(r'^-+(?:[^\S\n]+-+)*[^\S\n]*$', lambda x: x.group().replace('-', '='), text, flags=re.M)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew with \B-{2,}\B it makes all the dashes as group, so if i try to replace it with "=" it pouts only 2 =, i want every - to be replaced by = in the table

Comment: See my example code in the comment. It will work. It is exactly that: match the whole chunks of text, and replace the char with another one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i tried the update,it matches the whole -'s(not individual) as a single string, i want individual - to be replaced with =

Comment: You did not try **my code**

Comment: try here :- https://regex101.com/r/n4HuP8/1

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew I tried your code, it seems to work, I did some more testing & had put -'s with out space at the end of the string, it repalced that also. Is it possible that it can replace - which are only in the table( there are 2 spaces between columns in table, maybe use that to identify it as  a table)

Comment: If the number of columns is two: `r'^-+[ ]{2}-+$'`. If any: ``r'^-+(?:[ ]{2}-+)*$'``. Replace `[ ]` with the exact whitespace delimiter if necessary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I Used this `re.sub(r'^-+(?:\s{2}-+)*$', lambda x: x.group().replace('-', '='), body, flags=re.M)`, but it seems to replace the dashes which are at the bottom of  the string.

Comment: You do not have any dashes at the bottom of the string in the question. And what does that mean, that is matches them? Shouldn't it? Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201490/discussion-between-penta-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, is it possible to use negative look ahead & behind like i tried it in this question `(?<!\w)-\s{2}(?!\w) `  , such that it matches only table's column's dashes & nothing else

Comment: I leave my answer as a comment, as it does not match after your edits anymore. As long as you don't have any other `--` and the requirement is to replace at least two `-` I'd simply use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to replace any hyphens that are followed or preceded by another hyphen: [`-(?=-)|(?<=-)-`](https://regex101.com/r/76fcY7/1). As per your edit I can only think of using [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) eg like [`(?:\G|^(?=-+ )|(?<=- ))-`](https://regex101.com/r/p9ngQy/2). There are many options with it.